# Why is "Martenot" in “ondes Martenot” capitalised but not “theremin”?

Tags: capitalization

Usage including that in the respective Wikipedia pages shows "Martenot" in "ondes Martenot" and "theremin" are capitalised differently.

Léon Theremin developed [the theremin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theremin) in 1918, and Maurice Martenot invented [the ondes Martenot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ondes_Martenot) in 1928. "Ondes" is “waves” in French.

Why does one keep the capitalisation of its creator's name but not the other?

Comment: And of course, it's a *saxophone,* and not a *Saxophone*, in spite of the fact that it was invented by Adolphe Sax.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vaguely:

1. Theremins are slightly better known than ondes Martenot. Not being capitalised is the norm for English words, and like pebbles in a river words lose unusual features the more they are used. A similar thing often happens with genericised trademarks (those who call all vacuum cleaners *hoovers* regardless of manufacturer, would normally not capitalise it).
2. The name *ondes Martenot* more clearly refers to its manufacturer. Even if one didn't see immediately that *Martenot* was a surname, one would wonder "waves what?" and then learn this was the case. Conversely, one might not realise that *theremin* came from the westernised form of the name *Termen* / *Терме́н*.
3. Of the various names first used for theremins, all were lower-case, and some included its inventors name (whether the Westernised *Theremin* or the more directly transliterated *Termen*);  *thereminophone*, *termenvox*, *thereminvox*. From the various suggested names (along with *ætherphone* in a few spellings), the final name *theremin* was arrived at less directly from *Theremin* than was *ondes Martenot* from *Martenot*.

I say "vaguely" because there's no hard and fast rule about how these things will turn out, though in this case the last point made the lack of capitalisation on *theremin* particularly likely.